# Unable to resolve "@pnp/graph"' has no exported member named 'graph' in SPFX solution

Tags: spfx-webparts, pnpjs, pnp-js-core, graph-api

I have an SPFX solution where I am trying to use Graph API.
I tried installing 'npm install @pnp/logging @pnp/core @pnp/queryable @pnp/graph --save'

Now, while using 'import { graph } from "@pnp/graph"' I am getting below error.

```
'"@pnp/graph"' has no exported member named 'graph'.
```

Please guide me if anything I am missing here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `graph` was changed to `graphfi` in PnPjs v3.

[image]

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/transition-guide/#global-vs-instance-architecture

Here's a simple example of the use of `graphfi` from the PnPjs documentation.

```
import { SPFx, graphfi } from "@pnp/graph";
import "@pnp/graph/users";

// within a webpart, application customizer, or adaptive card extension where the context object is available
const graph = graphfi().using(SPFx(this.context));

const meData = await graph.me();
```

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/authentication/#spfx-graph